# Return value in consecutive cells if preceding cell equals value

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a column (call it column A) of Ws and Ls corresponding to Wins and Losses along with some blank cells in between. In an adjacent column (call it column B), I'm trying to use conditional formatting to either return the values as they are in column A or if there are 2 consecutive Ls in a row I want the next 10 consecutive cells to be blank then pick right back up with taking from whatever is in column A.

I feel like I'm pretty well-versed in conditional formatting, but this has me completely stumped and I can't come up with anything that is even close.

Here's an example of what I want it to look like:

[image]

As you can see, sometimes the two consecutive Ls are back-to-back and sometimes they occur with space in between, but either way, I need the same result (i.e., 10 consecutive blank cells immediately following the second "L")

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Was the answer provided helpful? Were you able to achieve what you wanted based on the answer? If so, please mark question as answered.

Comment: @radulle Apologies, I'm trying to implement your solution, but not getting anything close to what I need on my actual dataset (see edited post above). I've rechecked the formulas to make sure they match yours and indeed, they do. One thing I noticed (not sure whether it's the actual issue or not)... column D in your example is returning TRUE even when the last 2 values in the concatenated value are not LL? Thanks again for continued help.

Comment: I noticed that now, in that column instead of -2 it should be -1. I fixed it in the linked xlsx. Check again please.

Comment: @radulle Still not working... I've updated with an image above. Green column is what it should be (I've manually input that column). Result column immediately to the left is what I'm getting based on my implementation of your solution. This is my actual data set.

Comment: Have you tried using =IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("LL",A1&A2&A3&A4&A5&A6&A7&A8&A9&A10),0)>=1,"",A10) in column B?

Comment: Yes, that didn't work either.

Comment: So you want to have empty 10 lines after first LL? You want to ignore the rest of LLs in that group of 10?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As soon as there's a first LL in the sequence, 10 empty lines no matter what. Then pick right back up with pulling from the original data column. As soon as there's another LL, 10 more blank rows, then pick back up and on and on...

Comment: I finally understand what you wanted and updated my answer to fit your needs. You can try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I try to avoid using the `OFFSET` function because it is volatile, but in this case it should not matter since OP's objective is to use `Conditional Formatting`.

*Be aware that a cell value can not be modified by a `Conditional Formatting`.*

Assuming the data starts at `A2`, enter this formula in `B2` and copy till last row with data:

Using `CONCAT` function:

```
= IF( ROWS( $2:2 ) <= 2, T( $A2 ),
 IF( AND( SUM( B1 ) > 0, SUM( B1 ) < 10 ), SUM( 1, B1 ),
 IF( "LL" <> RIGHT( CONCAT( OFFSET( B2, -1, 0,
 - IF( ROWS( 1:$2 ) > 10, 10, ROWS( 1:$2 ) ) ) ), 2 ), T( $A2 ), 1 ) ) )
```

Using `TEXTJOIN` function:

```
= IF( ROWS( $2:2 ) <= 2, T( $A2 ),
 IF( AND( SUM( B1 ) > 0, SUM( B1 ) < 10 ), SUM( 1, B1 ),
 IF( "LL" <> RIGHT( TEXTJOIN( "", 1, OFFSET( B2, -1, 0,
 - IF( ROWS( 1:$2 ) > 10, 10, ROWS( 1:$2 ) ) ) ), 2 ), T( $A2 ), 1 ) ) )
```

The formula above generates a counter 1 to 10 after the "LL" combination is found. Then you should add the `Conditional Formatting` to apply the same color to the Font and Interior when the following criteria is met:

```
= ISNUMBER( B2 )
```

[image]
*Font and interior color are different in order to show the formulas values.*

The `OFFSET` function is used to set the range of 10 rows above the cell to be evaluated by the conditional format. *Note that the range is generated using the already evaluated values rather than the original ones (i.e. use column `B` instead of `A` )*

```
OFFSET( A2, -1, 1,
 - IF( ROWS( B1:B$2 ) > 10, 10, ROWS( B1:B$2 ) ) )
```

This part avoids running unnecessary comparisons:

```
IF( ROWS( B1:B$2 ) < 3, T( A2 ), … )
```

The use of the `T` function avoids the `zero` value when the cell is empty:

```
T( A2 )
```

This part initiates and terminates the counter:

```
IF( AND( SUM( B1 ) > 0, SUM( B1 ) < 10 ), SUM( 1, B1 ), …
```

The `TEXTJOIN` function concatenates the range generated by the `OFFSET` function.

**EDIT: REVISED FORMULAS**

You could also try the following *No Volatile* Formulas:

*Using `CONCAT` function:*

```
= IF( ROWS( $2:2 ) <= 2, T( $A2 ),
 IF( AND( SUM( B1 ) > 0, SUM( B1 ) < 10 ), SUM( 1, B1 ),
 IF( "LL" <> RIGHT( CONCAT( B1  : INDEX( B:B,
 ROW() - IF( -1 + ROWS( $2:2 ) > 10, 10, -1 + ROWS( $2:2 ) ) ) ), 2 ), T( $A2 ), 1 ) ) )
```

*Using `TEXTJOIN` function:*

```
= IF( ROWS( $2:2 ) <= 2, T( $A2 ),
 IF( AND( SUM( B1 ) > 0, SUM( B1 ) < 10 ), SUM( 1, B1 ),
 IF( "LL" <> RIGHT( TEXTJOIN( "", 1, B1:INDEX( B:B,
 ROW() - IF( -1 + ROWS( $2:2 ) > 10, 10, -1 + ROWS( $2:2 ) ) ) ), 2 ), T( $A2 ), 1 ) ) )
```

*Using `CONCATENATE` function:*

```
= IF( ROWS( $2:2 ) <= 2, T( $A2 ),
 IF( AND( SUM( B1 ) > 0, SUM( B1 ) < 10 ), SUM( 1, B1 ),
 IF( "LL" <> RIGHT( CHOOSE( IF( ROWS( 2:$4 ) > 10, 10, ROWS( 2:$4 ) ),
 CONCATENATE( B$2, B$3 ),
 CONCATENATE( B$2, B$3, B$4 ),
 CONCATENATE( B$2, B$3, B$4, B$5 ),
 CONCATENATE( B$2, B$3, B$4, B$5, B$6 ),
 CONCATENATE( B$2, B$3, B$4, B$5, B$6, B$7 ),
 CONCATENATE( B$2, B$3, B$4, B$5, B$6, B$7, B$8 ),
 CONCATENATE( B$2, B$3, B$4, B$5, B$6, B$7, B$8, B$9 ),
 CONCATENATE( B$2, B$3, B$4, B$5, B$6, B$7, B$8, B$9, B$10 ),
 CONCATENATE( B$2, B$3, B$4, B$5, B$6, B$7, B$8, B$9, B$10, B$11 ),
 CONCATENATE( INDEX(B:B,ROW()-10),
 INDEX(B:B,ROW()-9), INDEX(B:B,ROW()-8), INDEX(B:B,ROW()-7),
 INDEX(B:B,ROW()-6), INDEX(B:B,ROW()-5), INDEX(B:B,ROW()-4),
 INDEX(B:B,ROW()-3), INDEX(B:B,ROW()-2), INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1) ) ), 2 ), T( $A2 ), 1 ) ) )
```

Comment: I feel like this definitely should work... would there be a reason I'm receiving an invalid name error (i.e. #NAME?) when I copy down? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, TEXTJOIN is not available in Excel 2016 and prior.

Comment: @Abb what excel version are you using?

Comment: Updated using CONCAT function

Comment: You mentioned getting the `#NAME` when copying down the formula, do you get it also when entering the formula in `B2`?

Comment: No, I don’t. I’d have to go back and double check but I believe it only starts after the 3rd or 4th row and continues on for the entire dataset.

Comment: In which cell starts your data and in which cell are you applying the formula? (i.e. `A6`, `B6`, etc )

Comment: @EEM If I start in B2 and copy down, the invalid name error begins in B5 and continues on.

Comment: Try copying the formula from the answer and pasting it in cell `B2', I just did that and have no errors.

Comment: After the four row this section of the formula is applied: `IF( "LL" <> RIGHT( TEXTJOIN( "", 1, OFFSET( A4, -1, 1,
 - IF( ROWS( B$2:B3 ) > 10, 10, ROWS( B$2:B3 ) ) ) ), 2 ), T( A4 ), 1 ) ) )`. Suggest to check the spelling fo the functions. I was able to replicate your problem when entering the formula with any of the functions wrongly written (i.e. `OFSET` instead of `OFFSET`, etc)

Comment: The error is happening regardless if I copy/paste the formula from here into the worksheet or write it out myself. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tf4PUm8M66Px7_nNMLVVFOdVVZ0ycjjC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205780/discussion-between-eem-and-abb).

Answer (score 0):

1) Set each cell in column B equal to its column A counterpart (in B1 enter =A1 and drag)

2) Select a range column B, don't select between B1 and B11. In the conditional formatting box enter this formula

=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10="L"),--(A2:A11="L"))

3) Set formatting to white font with no background

4) Drag the formatting up and down to cover the entire column.

Comment: I also can't get this method to give me the correct result. Tried it a bunch of different ways, but still no luck. If I'm understanding correctly, selecting cells B2:B12 and then entering the formula in the conditional formatting box should work, correct?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion (edit incoming)
Just do it in B12 and drag it. You can drag to B1:B11, you just can't start there.

Answer (score 0):

This needs additional columns. I added a column for every step so it is easier to follow but you can merge sections.

Formulas:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Working example:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiTFgUFVzyzVgZxHPpALDGxkYd6lCA

Explanation per column:

```
A. Data
B. Concatenate last 10 rows
C. Length of concatenated value
D. Check if last two values in concatenated value are LL
E. Current row must be equal to L
F. Both conditions must be TRUE
G. Add 10 if TRUE if previous not equal to 0 or reduce by 1
H. Data shown only for rows where previous check is 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! What cell am I supposed to be entering this in (using the example data)? I've tried using this formula in a number of different cells/ways and am not getting the correct result? To clarify in case there's any confusion... in the above example, column A is the data I have and column B is the correct result I'm after using a formula (I entered column B manually just to show what I want the final result to look like).

Comment: Ok, than it is a bit more complicated. I updated the answer to cover your exact case.

Comment: If I may make a suggestion based on what I understand of your approach:

=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("LL",A1&A2&A3&A4&A5&A6&A7&A8&A9&A10),0)>=1,"",A10)

Starting in cell B10 and dragging down. 

This won't touch on conditional formatting but will get the job done.

Comment: True, this is not conditional formatting but maybe very complicated formula could be merged to produce it. I find conditional formatting problematic in cases where you need to export data into csv or copy/paste anywhere else and having more columns and steps like this is easier to debug and understand when you get back to it after a few months.

Comment: And if needed you can always base conditional formatting on the column G and just hide helper columns afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Let cell `B12` have this formula:
`=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("LL",TEXTJOIN("",false,A1:A11))),A12,"")`

Drag copy that formula up and down `column B`

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to work either. Looking at your example, it appears this formula inserts ten blanks even when the two Ls are not in a row. In the most recent comments above, I provide further clarification.

Comment: Edited: changed `A2:A12` to `A1:A12`. Give it another try.

You want it to refresh the 10 blanks every time it sees LL? or if there is an occurrance of LL while blanking, those LLs do not refresh the 10-count?

Comment: If there's an occurrence of LL while blanking, those LLs do not refresh the 10-count. From comments above... As soon as there's a first LL in the sequence, 10 empty lines no matter what. Then pick right back up with pulling from the original data column. As soon as there's another LL, 10 more blank rows, then pick back up and on and on..

Comment: Again, not sure if it's a mistake on my part, but neither formula seems to be working.